# How collections with Objects reacts?

Tags: java, methods, collections

my program contains an object and i want to understand how a collections that contains objects is helping me if i can`t use the methods ?

My code that i used :

```
ClassMain c = new ClassMain();
Map<String, ClassMain> s = new HashMap<>();
s.put("S", c);
Iterator it = s.keySet().iterator();

while(it.hasNext())
{
    Object key = it.next();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

ClassMain :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

public void print(){
    System.out.println("Printing");
}
```

Comment: You need to use generics.

Comment: "if i can`t use the methods" ?? What is the question?

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: @RC i want to know what is collections used for.

Comment: @user3385390 a collection is something used to store a bunch of things, is that what you are asking?

Comment: @RC yes , but i meant to HashMap is it the same ?, why HashMap contains objects ?

Comment: @user3385390: `Map` is an interface, `HashMap` is an implementing class.

Comment: I would advise some reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Comment: @RC Yes , i have learned from that site but it too complicated and full of useless information, do you have something else ?

Comment: Maybe the truth is in the *useless* parts...

Comment: No, this is a complicated subject.  Anything less complicated than the Oracle tutorials would barely scratch the surface.  The information there is all pertinent and relevant.  Perhaps you'd like to ask some more specific questions about the parts you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Iterator is a generic type. But you use it as a raw type. So you lose the type information it should have.

The code should be:

```
Iterator<String> it = s.keySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Or simpler:

```
for (String key : s.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) and you don't have to use it:

```
Iterator it = ... ;
```

[`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) returns a parameterized `Set<K>` which you can use here, as do all of the Collections methods that return another kind of Collection:

```
Iterator<String> = s.keySet().iterator();
```

This will let you use the objects returned by `next` as the actual type you've supplied to the Map:

```
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String key = it.next();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Collections are used for, well storing collections of things. You can pull out the objects in a `Map` like so:

```
ClassMain c = new ClassMain();
Map<String, ClassMain> s = new HashMap<String, ClassMain>();
s.put("S", c);

for (String key : s.keySet())
{
    ClassMain c = s.get(key);
    c.print();
}
```